# Could not load file or assembly Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

I am developing a website on ASP.NET in C# (.NET Framework 4). After creating a new website project I tried to run the project. But I am getting the below error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myfirst\159977c5\b9e740fc\App_global.asax.yfqtni9g.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I already went through the below links [and all speaks about access to the folder], but it didn't help me :(

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496875/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-file-c-windows-microsoft-net-framework-v4-0

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784157/asp-net-corrupt-assembly-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-app-web

http://web.archive.org/web/20101023213019/http://www.yetanotherdeveloper.com/post/2008/08/10/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-App_Web.aspx

I checked and gave full access "Temporary ASP.NET Files" and to its sub folders and files for Users user-group.

#### Assembly Load Trace

`WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].`

#### Stack Trace

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myfirst\4ff7194b\2da62764\App_global.asax.h-eem9xt.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity) +28
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults.get_CompiledAssembly() +93
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +60
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +16
System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +9118863
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +44
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +265

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myfirst\4ff7194b\2da62764\App_global.asax.h-eem9xt.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +62
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +421
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +31
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +691

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myfirst\4ff7194b\2da62764\App_global.asax.h-eem9xt.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258
```

### Please give me a link if this is a repeated question

Thanks in adv.

`I got the Log as follows


The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = John-PC\John
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///G:/WorkShop/HTML-CSS/ASP/MyFirst/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = G:\WorkShop\HTML-CSS\ASP\MyFirst\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myfirst\159977c5
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myfirst\159977c5
LOG: AppName = b9e740fc
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: G:\WorkShop\HTML-CSS\ASP\MyFirst\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.`

I am not able to trace any error. Please help me....

Comment: For more options see similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/1250797/52277

Answer (score 25):

I had simmilar problem after i tried to start performance tests.
I removed assemblyPostProcessorType attribute in `system.web` > `compilation` element in `web.config` and it worked again.

```
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1"  
            assemblyPostProcessorType="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspPerformanceInstrumenter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: where is the web.config file located?

Answer (score 9):

If you use Visual Studio Performance Tools then it is possible that Visual Studio left a key in your web.config appsettings section.  It causes a 32 bit library to load, which won't work if your application is loading in 64 bit mode.

Check for the following and remove it:

```
<add key="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper.VsInstrLocation" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\vsinstr.exe"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the solution is to delete those files from temporary asp.net folder that always works for me.

Comment: Hi Sumant, i deleted the Temp directory iteslf in the framework directory so  now i am getting the same error from Temp file as follows : "Error 1 Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myfirst\159977c5\b9e740fc\App_global.asax.r8qranjn.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  
"

Comment: This worked for me when I closed down Visual Studio and stopped my IIS website also.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher your tip helped me. I just stopped and then started IIS and the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following lines from web.config will resolve your error.

```
<compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have similar problem I think:
[Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ asp.net vs2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496875/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-file-c-windows-microsoft-net-framework-v4-0)

accepted answer was:

> Try performing a full solution build. If that doesn't work, click
>   Build -> Clean Solution. If the error persists, delete everything in
>   the C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\parktms folder and repeat.

Comment: HI Sarrus, i put the above link in my question itself. I deleted everything in Temporary ASP.NET Files folder. Still i am getting the same error.

Comment: I did a rebuild and republish and that didn't fix this issue but clean then republish to the server did.

Answer (score 2):

In my case while deploying an ASP.NET MVC project I renamed the DLL of one of the projects (the Assembly Name) in Visual Studio application properties.

Inside the Views folder of the ASP.NET MVC project sits a `Web.config` file. This `Web.config` file has the following `razor` section where we can list assemblies for nice IntelliSense support in Razor view files:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="VizionLogs.LogRepository" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

My problem: I renamed the project assembly from `VizionLogs.LogRepository` to `ITVizion.VizionLogs.LogRepository` and forgot to rename it in that `Web.config` file. This was causing that ASP.NET Temp folder error telling me it could not find `VizionLogs.LogRepository`. It took me some time to figure out what was going on and where the error was... :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Registry and enter

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion]
"EnableLog"=dword:00000001
"LogFailures"=dword:00000001
"LogPath"="c:\\temp\\fusionLog"
```

For loaded assembly you will find a log in c:\temp\fusionLog

There you will find what dependency is missing.

Comment: HI Peter, i am not sure how to add the three registry you mentioned. Please help me . i am  in the [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion] directory

Comment: I did it. righclick-> New->Dword.

Comment: Do not forget to disable/delete fusion log afterwards. It will fill disk with log files and take a little on performance.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I just solve it by changing
on web.config -> system.web -> compilation -> debug="false".
Then it work fine

Answer (score 0):

removing temporary projects files in corresponding folder like for .net 4 from below folder will resolve the issue.

**"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"**

also refer to this answer.

[Answered by Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422682/2315972)

Answer (score 0):

Please backup and remove the folder myfirst\159977c5\b9e740fc\App_global.asax.yfqtni9g.dll'

Answer (score 0):

Removing contents inside  (web.config) block worked for me for a similar issue.

a)  Following describe why you should remove it
[What exactly does <system.codedom>/<compilers> do in web.config in MVC 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545520/what-exactly-does-system-codedom-compilers-do-in-web-config-in-mvc-5)

Following Additional article from microsoft helps understand the concept

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms366723(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

**Compilation Folder Location**:

By default, when you compile a Web application the compiled code is placed in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder. This folder is a subdirectory of the location where you installed the .NET framework

Besides this, another article suggested double-checking the targetFramework and framework installed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I locate the bin folder in web.config as follow :

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="webSettingFolder" value="C:\Users\ali eshghi\source\repos\SalesWebApiDotNetFramWork\SalesWebApiDotNetFramWork\bin\"/>
  </appSettings>
```

after that the error has vanished.