# I am getting error that could not load file or assembly error because App_ global.aspx not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In visual studio 2015 when i creat asp.net web project and run it works fine. But after i restart my pc and try to open and run that project it shows me that the it could not load file or assembly b/c system could not find App_global.asax.dll.
The project builds successfully, this error happen when i browse or run it.
I have tried to
Run VS in administrative mode
Reinstall visual studio but it wont work.
Please help.

This is the full error message I get:

[image: this is the full error message i get]

Comment: Could be because of multiple reasons. Maybe you can take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525211/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-temporary-asp-net-files

Comment: Thanks joe, I have tried all the listed solutions but non of them works for me.